# How do I merge SQL query results with same SELECT and FROM values but different WHERE clauses?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two SQL queries:

The first lists all trial accounts
The second lists all accounts that are NOT disabled

My aim is to merge the two queries to end up with a list of trial organisations that are NOT disabled.

Trial Accounts:

```
SELECT Account_username, Institution
FROM Accounts, Attributes, Attribute_values
WHERE Attributes.Attribute_type_number=43
    and Accounts.Account_number=Attributes.Subject
    and Attributes.Attribute_number=Attribute_values.Attribute_number
    and Attribute_values.Attribute_value = 'TRIAL'
```

Results:

### UN      Institution

org1    Organisation 1
org2    Organisation 2
org3    Organisation 3

Not disabled accounts:

```
SELECT Account_username, Institution, Account_number
FROM Accounts, Attributes, Attribute_values
WHERE Attributes.Attribute_type_number=73
    and Accounts.Account_number=Attributes.Subject
    and Attributes.Attribute_number=Attribute_values.Attribute_number
    and Attribute_values.Attribute_value != 'disabled'
```

Results:

### UN      Institution

org2    Organisation 2
org4    Organisation 4
org5    Organisation 5

The end result should just list the following as it is a trial, and it is not disabled.

org2 Organisation 2

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want something like this:

```
SELECT A.Account_username, A.Institution
FROM Accounts AS A
INNER JOIN Attributes AS AT_Trial
    INNER JOIN Attribute_values AS AT_TrialVal
        ON AT_Trial.Attribute_number = AT_TrialVal.Attribute_number
    ON A.Account_number = AT_Trial.Subject
INNER JOIN Attributes AS AT_Enabled
    INNER JOIN Attribute_values AS AT_EnabledVal
        ON AT_Enabled.Attribute_number = AT_EnabledVal.Attribute_number
    ON A.Account_number = AT_Enabled.Subject
WHERE AT_Trial.Attribute_value = 'TRIAL'
  AND AT_Enabled.Attribute_value != 'disabled'
```

I didn't tested it. Let me know if you have some trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INTERSECT` for this.

> INTERSECT returns distinct rows that are output by both the left and right input queries.

```
SELECT Account_username, Institution,Account_number
FROM Accounts, Attributes, Attribute_values
WHERE Attributes.Attribute_type_number=43
    and Accounts.Account_number=Attributes.Subject
    and Attributes.Attribute_number=Attribute_values.Attribute_number
    and Attribute_values.Attribute_value = 'TRIAL'

INTERSECT

SELECT Account_username, Institution, Account_number
FROM Accounts, Attributes, Attribute_values
WHERE Attributes.Attribute_type_number=73
    and Accounts.Account_number=Attributes.Subject
    and Attributes.Attribute_number=Attribute_values.Attribute_number
    and Attribute_values.Attribute_value != 'disabled'
```

Comment: now is ok. I have tried to let a comment about -1 but answer was temporarily deleted.